# Unified Diff in TFS

Tags: tfs

Anyone know if this (generating a unified diff) is possible and if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Patch with TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234/creating-a-patch-with-tfs)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's `tf diff /shelveset:<set> /format:unified`. However, note that unlike most modern version-control systems, TFS can't actually work with patch files afaik. That is, you can't take the result of the diff and apply it to a set of files to get the resulting changes. (What most people do is zip up the files that changed and drop-and-replace that as a "patch". Ick.)

Comment: John, would you know how to output the results to a diff tool rather than to the command window?  I accidentally found that doing /options:? would go to my default merge tool (TortoiseMerge.exe) in the absence of a /format:unified option, but I couldn't get it to go there with the unified option on.

Also, I can only see my own shelvesets - would like to see all shelvesets for the team - is that possible, or do I have to run tf.exe from the server?

Comment: perfect - thanks.  for others like myself who may not know, tf.exe is here (unless you installed somewhere else) - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE.  Here's a reference:  http://tutorial.visualstudioteamsystem.com/details.aspx?item=38.

Comment: I figured out how to get this to output to a .diff file.  Type the command: "tf diff /format:unified [/shelveset:<set>] >filename.diff"  Then, if you have anything installed (like TortoiseSVN) that will deal with the .diff format, just open it. et voila!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your earlier comments until just now. Piping to standard output is pretty much what I would have gone with too, so it sounds like you're all set!

Comment: I created a feature request here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/631052/ability-to-import-or-use-a-unified-diff-patch-file-in-tfs

Answer (score 17):

This is what I usually do:

- Generate a unified diff from tf command line to get a patch file

  ```
  tf diff /recursive /format:unified .  >> diff.patch
  ```
- Download patch utility from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm
- Apply patch with

  ```
  patch.exe -p0 < diff.patch
  ```

Obviously this assumes that the source files are already checked out. If they are not, especially when you are applying patches across branches, write a simple shell script to go through the diff file, get the files path and tf edit them.

Comment: for my setup(windows 7, tfs 2013) creating a patch from tfs2013 is ok, but patch utility cannot apply those patches, to similiar files.  response is "can't find file to patch at input line 6
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?"

Answer (score 0):

This is an on-going feature diff (pardon the pun) with SubVersion and others, that is [recognised by Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/631052/ability-to-import-or-use-a-unified-diff-patch-file-in-tfs). I believe a solution will appear soon, however until then I have come up with a solution:

1. Build a windows forms application which will take 4 fields as command-line parameters (filepath1, label1, filepath2, label2) and returns a string unified diff of the two files (maybe output to a rich textbox or something).  I have one, but it is a bit rough to put up on CodePlex I believe.  There are a few managed Diff libraries.
2. Set Visual Studio's Source control compare function to point to your diff app. Make sure it opens and compares correctly.
3. Build a windows forms patch application, which will apply the patch to a folder. The application also has to check out each file as it is patched (fun!).
4. Setup two workspaces,  the usual one, and a MyWkSpace_PATCH. This is used to patch to.

I still have to finish of point 3, but this will give me somewhat similar functionality to SubVersion.  Will let you know how point 3 goes!