# Using patch files with TFS (patch file is from subversion, git, etc)

Tags: svn, git, tfs, patch

Can patch files be read by TFS or visual studio?  I'd like to either create a shelveset or apply the patch to a workspace in TFS.

Comment: To clarify your question: you have multiple version control systems. In one system you modify some code files and want to apply those changes to TFS also. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  The changes were made in GIT, the same code is also in TFS.  I can sync the changes from TFS into GIT manually, but haven't found a good way to move the changes from GIT back into TFS.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977309/unified-diff-in-tfs):

- You can create [unified diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) patch files with:

```
tf diff /format:unified [/shelveset:] >filename.diff
```

with `tf.exe` being usually here `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE` (See [tf Command-Line Utility Tool in Team Foundation Server](http://tutorial.visualstudioteamsystem.com/details.aspx?item=38)).

- You cannot import/use a patch file in TFS.

Answer (score 4):

I created a feature request here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/631052/ability-to-import-or-use-a-unified-diff-patch-file-in-tfs

Comment: I want to upvote your microsoft connect issue, but the Terms of Service for microsoft connect worried me.